# WP PHP Dynamic resizing or image size?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I got this WP theme mpcreation dot net.

Issue: I cannot get my grid image sizes http://thakurpress.com looking the same as theirs as on their example at http://products.mpcreation.net/?product=example.

I have digged around but still haven't a clue. Does any anyone have this theme or can any PHP genius help out?

So far I think it could be lurking in either the main index.php file or the portfolio.php files. However if it is set in their then it is dynamic resizing, if not it's another setting elsewhere in WP.

They have a fancy UI which you can also set the image size in, but no luck. The sizes available are 1:2,2:1,1:1,2:2. I think it should be 0.5:2 maybe? But even if this is right can I code this into the backend class?

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- I would look through the Theme Settings, or, more particularly, additional settings for an option to choose the image size.
- If there is no option, then it's probably decided randomly based on the images aspect ratio.
- If that's not satisfactory I would contact the developer of the Theme and post in their forum.
- And if that still doesn't cut it you could use CSS and, possibly, "pseudo classes" to target alternating images to set a differing height.
- You could also write a PHP Hook Filter (but I understand that may be beyond your skill set?) to change the function that resizes the images. Though I think this is likely completely unnecessary.
- Finally, you could also try manually re sizing your images (like cropping them to a different aspect ratio) to see if that has an impact on how the Theme decides to style the image in the grid.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, great advice. Point 6 I've already tried with no change pulling through. Point 5 yeah best leave that try till last, but I might have to do this. Point 4 could possibly be less robust than solution/Point 5 if point 5 is implemented. Point 3 they want to charge, I want to learn instead, although I am shocked they want to charge for a 'simple' fix. Point 2 this is not the fact, as an option is available. Point 1 the image sizing is the only UI field I can see, but it only gives the ratios I posted in my question. Maybe I should post the two possible 'culprit' classes?

Comment: Regarding #2 when I refer to an option I mean something like this (confirm if I'm correct): You navigate to a menu item called "My Images" (or something). You see a list of the images, like you see a list of Posts on the Posts section, and there is an option on the right that says "Make this Square." or "Make this Vertical Rectangle" etc... And that's how it's decided what shape it uses. Is that the case? If not, what do **you** mean by options

Comment: Yes this is the case. See this http://www.thakurpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/wp-help.png, from this image what should I change? Thanks again

Comment: Well, that's the Media Library page and I don't see an option related to your Theme that allows you to change it's shape. All the controls I see there are native WordPress options.

Comment: In that case, there is no custom page for images for the posts. In this theme posts are called Portfolio. So each portfolio item is a post. Here is a screen shot of the post pages http://www.thakurpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/wp-help2.png, then see http://www.thakurpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/wp-help3.png then see http://www.thakurpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/wp-help4.png

Comment: Wonder if those make sense as to where I change the setting. Thanks Spencer

Comment: I see, so they're Custom Post Types (just an FYI that's an important distinction between "Posts" and "Custom Post Type" - which is Portfolio in your case). Can you give me a better resolution version of the second screenshot?

Comment: Sorry Spencer, I have replaced this theme with another. Thanks for all your help! At the end of the day it's the websites success that matters not the theme! Plus I won't use that company again as they have bad and charged customer support! Thanks again buddy. I want to post it though for the sake of learning! :)

Comment: Yup, you're welcome! If I was helpful I greatly appreciate "upping" my post here to help my reputation. Thanks!